# Apache - What' s the Dokumentroot directive ?

Tags: apache, directive

For me in Debian even the default didn' t worked , given in Apache' s webpage .

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/de/mod/core.html#documentroot, auf Deutsch!

Comment: but what ' s the configuration file in that documentroot is . I have looked after all the ones in the directory where the main config. file is.

Comment: Let us know which Linux distribution you use, since the installation directories vary form one to the other.  You are usally looking for `httpd.conf` as the main configuration file that points to others (via includes).

Answer (score 0):

Basically, DocumentRoot Directive Used to Specify Actual path of webpage or Website Directory in a VirtualHost Container.

Example: (You can Write DocumentRoot Directive Like that in VirtualHost Container)

DocumentRoot /var/www/xyz.com/

Read This :

1. Host Your actual web content in this directory : /var/www/html
2. Apache configuration directory : /etc/apache2
3. Apache main configuration file : /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
4. This file specifies the ports that Apache will listen on : /etc/apache2/ports.conf
5. /etc/apache2/sites-available/ : The directory where per-site virtual hosts can be stored. (Apache will not use the configuration files found in this directory unless they are linked to the sites-enabled directory.)
6. /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ : The directory where enabled per-site virtual hosts are stored. (these are created by linking to configuration files found in the sites-available directory)
7. /etc/apache2/mods-available/, /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ : These directories contain the available and enabled modules, respectively.

Comment: Just a small note that this answer is based on a default setup on a certain linux distribution (which one are you using?).  The directories vary from distro. to distro. and you can build it yourself to put it anywhere on the system.

Comment: Yes, i know that this answer is based on default setup. By the way, i'm using RHEL 7 & Centos 7. Yes, You can put it anywhere. But, if you put your file somewhere else rather than the default directory. Then you have specify directory control permission else it will won't work.